# what does [[...]] mean in python?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I tried to print a list which supposes to be(I think) a empty list, However I got a `[[...]]` instead. I tried to google it, but no luck. Futhermore, When I use slice to see what the hell is [`...`] in the strange list, I got the same `[[...]]`, I guess there would be some kind of recursive, but what leads to it ?Anyone knows why?

Comment: Maybe post some code leading to that output?

Comment: Thanks @Mat and Alasdair. I guess we should've looked for dupes before answering... but our answers add a _little_ bit to the info given at the dupe target. ;) But I guess the new question title is not search-engine friendly, even though it's otherwise clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. It's a list that contains itself recursively. Here's a simple way to create such a list:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[[...]]
```

Answer (score 4):

That means a list contains itself:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[[...]]
```

This is one way to get that -- a list with one element, *namely itself*.

Such a structure can't be printed (it recurses forever) so Python prints ellipsis to mean "and so on".